# Sort nvarchar column that have numbers and strings in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have problem in reporting services. Currently I use sorting from reporting services by my column and it's working if I have string values, but if I have numbers mixed with string values it doesn't. Problem is when values are mixed for example:

> 1,11,2,111,... ab,abc,bb.

I tried with:

```
=CInt(Fields!ColumnName.Value)
```

But this is good only if I have numbers as values in my column
How can I solve this in reporting services?

Comment: Which one you want to sort order first. Numeric or alphanumeric

Comment: Both, if i have numbers them numeric if i have alphabet then alphabetical

Answer (score 0):

Add two sort expressions

```
=VAL(Fields!ColumnName.Value)
```

and

```
=Fields!ColumnName.Value
```

Comment: Ok but how to implement this together with some IIF check?

Comment: You won't need to do any checks, the first sort will sort all the numbers and anything alphabetical will be sorted as zero, then the second sort will sort the 'zeros' by their alphabetical sorting. Just add the two sorts as I suggested and try it.